# How do I get a contained background image to cover the entire div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Ok, so my question is how do I make my image more responsive? I am a new coder, so I'm still trying to understand css more. I've tried using the contain value, but it doesn't cover the entire div. I also tried cover, but it doesn't show the entire image when it expands inside the div. If anybody has any ideas at all, I would love to hear from you. Thanks Also, it's not the same question as covering the entire page. I want the image to cover inside my div, and it doesn't seem to be working.

```css
.tribute {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 12%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 35%;
  background: url(dickgregory.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1 class="centerh1">Projects</h1>
    <hr class="portfoliohr">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/boiledbiscuit/pen/dzeMPW?q=dick+gregory&limit=all&type=type-pens" target="blank">
        <div class="tribute">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this link and see if you can find your answer :) https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your image **is** taking up the full `width` and `height` of your `.tribute` element. The problem is that you've both added `margin` to the `.tribute` element, and restricted its `width`.

Removing the margins and setting `width` to `100%` shows the image covering the full area as expected.

Note that `background-size: cover` may stretch or crop the image, and `background-size: contain` will **resize** the image to ensure that it is always visible.

This is best demonstrated with an example.

Contain:

```css
.tribute {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/310);
  background-size: contain;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
  <br>
  <br>
  <h1 class="centerh1">Projects</h1>
  <hr class="portfoliohr">
  <a href="https://codepen.io/boiledbiscuit/pen/dzeMPW?q=dick+gregory&limit=all&type=type-pens" target="blank">
    <div class="tribute">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Cover:

```css
.tribute {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/310);
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
  <br>
  <br>
  <h1 class="centerh1">Projects</h1>
  <hr class="portfoliohr">
  <a href="https://codepen.io/boiledbiscuit/pen/dzeMPW?q=dick+gregory&limit=all&type=type-pens" target="blank">
    <div class="tribute">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `cover` and `contain` are the best ways to handle an image that isn't the proportion you want. You could use an `<img>` tag instead of a div with a background image, if that would work for your use. Otherwise, I usually add a background color to the element that is similar to the image, so that it blends in better.

```css
.tribute {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 12%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 35%;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Dick_Gregory.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #666;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
  <br>
  <br>
  <h1 class="centerh1">Projects</h1>
  <hr class="portfoliohr">
  <a href="https://codepen.io/boiledbiscuit/pen/dzeMPW?q=dick+gregory&limit=all&type=type-pens" target="blank">
   <div class="tribute">
   </div>
  </a>
</div>
```